Is "masonry cream" necessary/helpful with penetrating damp?
We recently bought a 1920s brick house in Yorkshire and may have an issue with penetrating damp in an exterior north-facing wall. We recently spoke to a representative of a local company advertising as specialising in damp issues and they recommended a transparent "masonry cream" product which will - as I understand it - essentially waterproof that area of wall. However, we think a significant part of the recent problem was caused by a damaged gutter that allowed water to course over the external wall (now repaired) and online reviews of the masonry cream product seem mixed at best - some suggest it could be actively harmful in older homes. If anyone can explain whether products like this are a good or bad idea for this type of property/issue, and why, it would be appreciated.
(I've avoided naming it on purpose as it sounds like the company actively tracks mentions online and then promotes it, but it's named in the link)
(Question relating to the same overall issue: What is the glossy paint under our wallpaper, should I remove it and can I paint over it?)

Apart from potential changes in the colour and finish of the masonry, you are signing up for a periodic reapplication of the product over time. Maybe better to prove your theory that the gutter fix worked, first.
